# iRobot Create 2: Can I load the code in instead of connecting cable? (new learner)

Tags: irobot-create

I am a new learner of iRobot. I am trying to program it to control the movement of the Create 2. After glancing through the existing project, I find most of them are based on sending commands to Roomba through a cable.

Is there anyway to embed the code in and let the Roomba behave accordingly? If there is not such method, which kind of API tool do you think is easiest for beginner?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the old Create, there is no way for the new Create2 to store any user program.

Be warned, *easiest* is very subjective.  For me, the easiest thing is to write python code and place a small netbook on the robot.  For others, the easiest thing is to write Arduino code and wire that in...

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is that possible to embed the code in the old Create? Can I still find the old create in store?

Comment: The old Create had what was called the "command module" which contained a microcontroller that you could put code on.  But you can easily replicate this functionality yourself.  The old Create is no longer made or sold anymore.  (Unless someone has an inventory of them somewhere).